# Android | CardView stays above TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/create_workout_fab_container"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:background="@drawable/fab"
android:stateListAnimator="@anim/fab_elevation"
android:clickable="true"
>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/create_workout_fab_anim_helper"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_size"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_dark"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/fab_radius"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/create_workout_fab_label"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_ripple_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="+"
    android:textColor="@color/fab_label_color"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="+"
    tools:textColor="@color/fab_label_color"
    />



    </FrameLayout>
```

The CardView is only there to use it for an smooth animation from a cirle button to a rectangle view by animation a radius change.

But the problem is, wheneever the CardView becomes visible it stays above the TextView. Why is that and how do I get it to lay under the TextView

Comment: Are you testing on an Android 5.0 device?

Comment: Yes. I am working on an Android L device

Comment: Please refer to my answer for a similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/a/34496812/2936688](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34496812/2936688)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FrameLayout draws children in order, first to last. Therefore you need to swap the CardView with the TextView.

UPDATE:
Also if you are running on android L+ you need to set a higher elevation on the CardView than the TextView

Comment: I tried it in bith orders in the xml layout. I also tried it within a RelativeLayout, still the CardView is always on top.

Comment: @Gil Julio, on L+ the trick is to add a higher elevation on the element supposed to be on top of the card, not on the card.