# create view over cardview in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I want to create this layout
[image]

this is a cardview (gray view) and imageview(blue view) for that i use this code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard">


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ratingbar_full_material" />

</FrameLayout>
```

but in result my image view going to back of cardview i try reletivelayout instead of framelayout but same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

- Use a RelativeLayout
- Align the ImageView to the parent right/end and add a right/end margin
- Align the FAB to the top of the card view and add a negative margin

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...>
    <CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/cardView"
    android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i do that too but the interesting things is here that is not work with cardview i do that before with another type of view and works but cardview  no

Comment: Last try, wrap your card view with a linear layout

Comment: @cwfei please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393540/no-shadow-elevation-underneath-second-card-if-there-are-two-card-in-the-layout

Answer (score 50):

The CardView has by default elevation in API 21+, you can manipulate the elevation to be less than that of the ImageView

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:cardElevation="1dp"/>

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_user"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
         android:elevation="2dp"/>
```

in Pre 21 you can use

```
overlayView.bringToFront();
root.requestLayout();
root.invalidate();
```

This will not work in 21+ if you have different elevation

Answer (score 27):

Just put CardView in other view like in FrameLayout.
Just like below:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5sp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary">
    <!--other view items -->
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
     <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="90sp"
        android:layout_height="90sp"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:id="@+id/profileImg"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_if_profle_1055000"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Image over CardView]

Answer (score 6):

Just add elevation to ImageView greater than CardView elevation

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/abc_search_url_text_normal"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Elevation does change order of views

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap CardView in FrameLayout but then the shadow will be cropped.
 Set android:clipChildren="false" to fix it

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_height="140dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_radius"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way around it would be to wrap the image view in a card view. Just ensure the background is transparent with height and width wrapping content and it will go on top of the previous card view.